# Java saying everything is palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm writing a program that reads text from one file then determines if it's a palindrome. The one problem is, it thinks everything is one. Here's my code:

```
   String input = "";
   String reversed = "";
   String answer = "";
   int count = 0;
   int low = 0;
   int high = input.length() - 1;

   outF.println("Palindrome   Input String            New String");

   while (inF.hasNext()){
       input=inF.nextLine();
       reversed = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();
        boolean isPalindrome;
       while (low < high) {
         isPalindrome = true;
           if (input.charAt(low) != input.charAt(high)) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
         }
         low++;
         high--;

       }
       if (isPalindrome = true){
          answer = "yes";}
       else{
           answer = "no";}

       outF.printf("  %-10s %-23s %s %n", answer, input.trim(), reversed.trim());

       count++;
   }
```

And here's my output:

```
Palindrome   Input String            New String
  yes        STAR RATS               STAR RATS 
  yes        STAT                    TATS 
  yes        LEVEL                   LEVEL 
  yes        MALAYALAM               MALAYALAM 
  yes        Solos                   soloS 
  yes        kaya                    ayak 
  yes        Radar                   radaR 
  yes        Regal lageR             Regal lageR 
  yes        Straw wartS             Straw wartS 
  yes        RSTUVWXYZXWVUTSR        RSTUVWXZYXWVUTSR 
  yes        DeifieD                 DeifieD 
  yes        ABBA                    ABBA 
  yes        mama anna mama          amam anna amam 
  yes        noel leon               noel leon 
  yes        Racecar                 racecaR 
  yes        galleonnoelag           galeonnoellag 
end of program 16 strings were processed
```

Anyone know what may be causing this? I'm following what my book says to do for finding out if something is a palindrome which is

I moved some things around to look like this:
           boolean isPalindrome = true;
           while (low < high) {

```
           if (input.charAt(low) != input.charAt(high)) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
         }
         low++;
         high--;

       }
       if (isPalindrome ){
          answer = "yes";}
       else{
           answer = "no";}

       outF.printf("  %-10s %-23s %s %n", answer, input.trim(), reversed.trim());

       count++;
```

and it still isn't working. If I left it as is before it would try to say that the isPalindrome wasn't defined.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Look up variable scope. If you define a variable inside a loop, it isn't available outside the loop.

Comment: @JJJ what variable is he defining inside the loop and trying to use outside the loop?

Comment: Hint: Put a `System.out.println()` inside the `while (low < high)` loop, and display some of the important variables.  What you see--or what you don't see--may help you figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (inF.hasNext()){
   input=inF.nextLine();
   reversed = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();
    boolean isPalindrome;
int low = 0;
int high = input.length() - 1;

   while (low < high) {
     isPalindrome = true;
       if (input.charAt(low) != input.charAt(high)) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
     }
     low++;
     high--;

   }
```

Declare the `low` and `high` variables inside the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems with your code:

1. You declare isPalendrome inside your while()-loop. Because of this you can't access it from outside the loop. Simply move `boolean isPalindrome;` outside of your while()-loop.
2. You don't compare any variables with this statement 
   `if (isPalindrome = true){`. With a single = you assign a value to a variable. Because of this your if-Statement is always true. To compare two variables you have to use ==: `if (isPalindrome == true){`

EDIT: I also found some other problems:

1. `high = input.length() - 1;`  is always -1 in your programm. At this point it has to be `high = 0;` and `high = input.length() - 1;` inside the while()-loop, so that it is set to length-1 at each run through the while()-loop.
2. You have to reset low after each run: You have to declare `low = 0;` inside the while loop.

Now it works perfectly for me.

Comment: If #1 were a problem, he would have gotten a syntax error, instead of the wrong results.  There is no problem with the place where he declared `isPalindrome`.  Also, you're right about #2 but it appears that he fixed this.  There is still one more serious bug which you haven't noticed.